# C++. Namespaces and classes

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I develop a game with help of PopCap Framework.
I found this header in demo:

```
#ifndef __BOARD_H__
#define __BOARD_H__
#include "SexyAppFramework/Widget.h"
namespace Sexy
{
    class Graphics;
    class GameApp;
    class Board : public Widget
    {
        private:
        GameApp*    mApp;
        public:
        Board(GameApp* theApp);
        virtual ~Board();
        virtual void Draw(Graphics* g);
        virtual void Update();
    };
}
#endif // __BOARD_H__
```

What does the following mean?

```
namespace Sexy
{
}
```

I guess it means the same as

```
using namespace Sexy;
```

But for the code within braces, is this so?

And what does it mean?

```
class Graphics;
class GameApp;
```

Comment: Somebody here needs to grab [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642)...

Comment: Declaration would be interesting: `Sexy::Graphics object;`

Comment: `__BOARD_H__` is a reserved identifier, you should remove the leading underscores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
namespace X {code}
```

means that the code in the {} is in namespace X.

```
using namespace X;
```

means that the compiler should look up names you use in namespace X.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

```
class Graphics;
class GameApp;
```

are [forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)